# Clear People picker field in Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I am trying below code to clear people picker field but this does not work when i submit form

On People picker i set defaultselecteditems below so if user select Approve its set value blank in Peoplepicker

```
Switch(DataCardValue44.Selected.Value,
        "Approve",{Value:Blank()},)
```

and on Submit button i written below

```
Patch(
   Master,
    {ID: VarID},
    Form3_1.Updates
);
```

But it does  not clear value for people picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to reset a form is to use the `ResetForm()` function:

- Select your Form
- Open `OnSuccess` property
- Paste this code to reset the form:

```
ResetForm(YOUR_EDIT_NAME);
Back();
```

[image]

**You can also reset a specific control**

You can reset a specific control, for example, people picker using the `Reset()` function:

```
Reset(Person_DataCardValue)
```